# Building cvhaartraining.lib

Tags: windows, visual-studio, image-processing, opencv

I am trying to do some OpenCV work on Visual Studio 2010 and I am trying to compile the 'createsamples' project. I am getting linker errors when trying to do so and after much research online I've noticed that I am missing the cvhaartraining library. What do I need to do to compile this library for use in my projects. I have VS 2005, 2008, and 2010 at my disposal and I can switch to either one as long as I can get a build. I am working with OpenCV 2.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this? http://asadujjaman.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/building-opencv-with-microsoft-visual-studio/

Comment: I have tried it, but I get errors when trying to compile certain projects.

Comment: It works now. I had to build it in VS2010 because 2005 and 2008 were asking me for a DShow.h include and when I included the library I got C linker errors. Thanks for the help.